# postgreSQL: How Select the nearest date that is not null

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I got a date that I want to find the all records in the past that got the same month and day.
The problem accrues when there is no such date in the same year. For example, the 29th February.

My goal is to get the nearest date from below the date that does not exist.

This is my currently query with the date 2012-02-29:

```
SELECT date, amount
 FROM table_name
 WHERE
     EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE('2012-02-29') )
     AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE('2012-02-29') )
     AND date < '2012-02-29'
     ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: What about: `"date" = date '2016-02-29' - interval '1' year`

Comment: I execute this query on a lot of dates. 99% of them are without this problem.

Comment: so it is same month and day ALL YEARS?..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want one date per year with the property that that day is nearest to the given date.

I would suggest using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (date_trunc('year', date)) t.*
from table_name t
order by date_trunc('year', date),
         abs(date_part('day, (date -
                              (date '2012-02-29' -
                               (extract(year from date '2012-02-29') - extract(year from date)) * interval '1 year'
                               )
                              )
                             )
                      )
            );
```

EDIT:

An example of working code:

```
select distinct on (date_trunc('year', date)) t.*
from table_name t
order by date_trunc('year', date),
         abs(date_part('day', date - (date '2012-02-29' -
                       ((extract(year from date '2012-02-29') - extract(year from date)) * interval '1 year')
                      )
              ))
```

Comment: doesn't work on postgres.. it throw me error that '-' is operator that does not exist

Comment: @user5056295 . . . The idea works, but the code was off.  I hope I copied it over correctly this time.